# Hayageek jQuery file upload plugin pass extra data to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am using the excellent [Hayageek File Upload Plugin](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php), with progress bar.

The plugin allows one to specify the URL of the PHP file that processes the uploaded file(s), like this:

```
var uploadObj = $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url: "uploader.php",
    method: "POST",
    allowedTypes:"jpg", //,png,gif,doc,pdf,zip
    fileName: "myfile",
    multiple: false,
    autoSubmit: true,
    showStatusAfterSuccess:false,
    onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr) {
        alert( data );
    },
});
```

I wish to send (to the PHP side) an item ID along with the uploaded file. The `Advanced` tab on [Ravi's website (click Advanced manually)](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) shows that it is possible to send extra information to the PHP upload processor file using either:

```
formData: {"name":"Ravi","age":31},
```

or, dynamic info:

```
dynamicFormData: function() {
    var data ={ location:"INDIA"}
    return data;
},
```

*I am not clear on the difference between those two (how to use differently) -- would I not also be able to send dynamic data via the ordinary `formData:` parameter if using a variable, such as `formData: {"name": strName,"age": intAge},`?*

Anyway, my real problem is this next point: **there is no information about how to retrieve the extra information on the PHP side.** I assume the data is sent via JSON. I'm crap at JSON.

Here's what I tried - these attempts did not work (attempting to alert it in the `success:` function, as `alert(data)`:

**PHP:**

```
$formdat = json_decode($_POST['formData']);
echo $formdat.name;
```

Nor this:

```
$formdat = $_POST['formData'];
echo $formdat['name'];
```

How should I reference the formData - for example, the `name` or `age` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was so simple I didn't think to try it. For the three examples in original question above:

```
$n = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
```

and

```
$n = $_POST['location'];
echo $n; //alerts India
```

---

Source: this response thread in the Disqus comment section on author's website:

```
How to access dynamicFormdata in upload.php ??
Suresh Koduri

Rafael says:

** in javascript: **

dynamicFormData: function() {
    var data ={ location:"INDIA"}
    return data;
}

-------------------------------------

** in upload.php **

$location = $_POST["location"];
```